# Django with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I want send to ajax username of current user, so :

```
<a href="#" onclick="return goto_confirm({{ user.username }})" ><b>Eat</b></a>
```

My function js :

```
function goto_confirm(theusername){
    alert("Hello "+theusername.value);
    var eating;
    if(confirm("Are-you sure ?"))
        eating = true;
    else
        eating = false;

    return false;
}
```

But on click, I have this error :
**`ReferenceError: toto938 is not defined`**

"toto938" is the value of user.username...

Comment: Try with `goto_confirm('{{ user.username }}')`

Comment: Thank you very much. I use your solution and it works if I delete the ".value" else "undefined" is displayed. Thank you ;)